# ASP.net eTag cache thumbnail images on load/refresh

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, caching, etag

Hey all I have been working to get my 20+ thumbnails into a cache state so it doesn't always going the server to get the images each time the page is loaded/reloaded.

I have implemented the "eTag" into my response call like so:

```
var uriFetcher = new UriFetcher(fileUri);
var tempPath = uriFetcher.FetchFile();
var mime = MimeType(tempPath);

//displays like: xxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.png
//This is the image file name. These names do not change.
string theETag = tempPath.Split('\\').Last();

context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
context.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1));
context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
context.Response.CacheControl = "private";
context.Response.ContentType = mime;

//Add current image file name to the eTag
context.Response.AddHeader("ETag", "\"" + theETag + "\"");

var disposition = new ContentDisposition
{
    FileName = Path.GetFileName(tempPath),
    Inline = mime.Contains("image")
};

context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", disposition.ToString());

try {
   context.Response.TransmitFile(tempPath);
} catch {
   context.Response.TransmitFile(errorUri);
}
```

Now after the .cs part above it goes to a JavaScript function that's using the jQuery framework in order to place it onto the page for the user to see:

```
var imgThumbnail = img('thumbnail', '/' + thumbnailId + '/Thumbnail', preload)
    .tipsy({
        html: true,
        assetMode: false,
        fallback: assetData.Tooltip.html(),
        gravity: ($container.closest('#Side').length == 0) ? $.fn.tipsy.auto : 'e',
        topOffset: topOffset
    });
if (assetData.ProcessingRollupStatus != null) {
    if (assetData.ProcessingRollupStatus === 'Processing') {
        imgThumbnail.addClass('processing-status-processing');
    } else if (assetData.ProcessingRollupStatus === 'Waiting') {
        imgThumbnail.addClass('processing-status-waiting');
    }
}

$container
    .addClass('asset-item')
    .data('AssetData', assetData)
    .attr('id', assetData.Id)
    .append(imgThumbnail);
```

And from Firefox this is what the output looks like:

[image]

[image]

So the part where I am having issues is when I go check for the eTag when the page is loaded/refreshed. I'm not really sure what (or where) I should put that code in order for it to **not** load the images if they are already in cache?

I was thinking something like this:

```
var requestedETag = context.Request.Headers["If-None-Match"];

if (requestedETag == last)
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotModified);
    //context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(304);
} else {
   ...........
```

So, anyone care to enlighten me as to how to go about doing this check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the correct way of doing this:

```
var uriFetcher    = new UriFetcher(fileUri);
var tempPath      = uriFetcher.FetchFile();
var mime          = MimeType(tempPath);
string imgName    = tempPath.Split('\\').Last();
var requestedETag = context.Request.Headers["If-None-Match"];

if (requestedETag != imgName && requestedETag != null)
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = 304;
    context.Response.StatusDescription = "Not Modified";
}
else
{
   var disposition = new ContentDisposition
   {
       FileName = Path.GetFileName(tempPath),
       Inline   = mime.Contains("image")
   };

   context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndPrivate);
   context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
   context.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
   context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddYears(1));
   context.Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0));
   context.Response.CacheControl = "private";
   context.Response.ContentType = mime;
   context.Response.AddHeader("ETag", "\"" + imgName + "\"");
   context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", disposition.ToString());

   try
   {
      context.Response.TransmitFile(tempPath);
   }
   catch
   {
      context.Response.TransmitFile(errorUri);
   }
}
```

In the **first time** load of the particular page it defines the **eTag** that is the unique name that the image has (**imgName**). The **unique image name** would be something like **iAmAnImage123.png** for an **example**.

If the user **refreshes** the page it then goes into the "**If-None-Match**" check which has the **unique image name**. This is being **compared** to the **current image eTag** name that is being loaded.

In **my case** I went from loading **1 MB** each time the user **loaded/refreshed** the page:

[image]

to just **1 MB at first** then only **158.80 KB** thereafter. An **835.80 KB** savings!:

[image]

So **basically** it looks like this when its at the If statement above:

```
 |-> Question: Hey has iAmAnImage123.png already been loaded before? 
  |-> Yes: Well then, skip it and pass a 304 to the browser to let them know that
           its already been cached then go on to the next image. 
  |-> No: Alright, lets load it and then remember it by adding a unique eTag to
          it which we will be calling it iAmAImage123.png.
```